# Android line drawing error in xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

how can I write this -------- or -------- in the android xml file. though I used hyphen but there will be a line , then or and then line (see the link for image)

i have seen some answers here in stackoverflow but they are only lines and the texts are not inside there. So I could not find my answer.

link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_sWfoxiwU4jZmokH0lmtAkEUiXU2N-2QTDpL9NsMj_g/edit

Comment: 2 `View` with specified width and height and TextView on the middle, follow like this: `View(margin)TextView(margin)View`

Comment: Sorry i can't understand. Can you please write the xml? I tried View but that only draws a line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    />
    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="or"/>
     <View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    />
```

You can use something like this

Answer (score 0):

Sure You can. Use this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#999999"
    android:dashGap="2dp"
    android:dashWidth="2dp" />

<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

and then in the View, use layerType="software" setting the drawable as background.

```
<android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="3dp"
 android:background="@drawable/line_promo"
 android:layerType="software" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Create a XML Drawable like this.

**drawable/_line.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
     android:bottom = "-1dp"
     android:left = "-1dp"
     android:right = "-1dp"
     android:top = "0dp">

    <shape android:shape = "line">
      <stroke
         android:width = "1dp"
         android:color = "#000"
         android:dashGap = "0dp"
         android:dashWidth = "5dp"/>
      <solid android:color = "@android:color/transparent"/>

      <padding
         android:bottom = "10dp"
         android:left = "10dp"
         android:right = "10dp"
         android:top = "10dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then in your layout file Create view and set the above  xml as drawable for it like this.

**your_layout_file.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
   android:layout_height = "match_parent"
   android:background = "#ffffff"
   android:gravity = "center"
   android:orientation = "horizontal">

  <View
     android:layout_width = "50dp"
     android:layout_height = "5dp"
     android:background = "@drawable/_line"/>

  <TextView
     android:id = "@+id/tv"
     android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity = "center"
     android:layout_marginLeft = "@dimen/pad_5"
     android:layout_marginRight = "@dimen/pad_5"
     android:gravity = "center"
     android:text = "or"
     android:textSize = "24sp"/>

  <View
     android:layout_width = "50dp"
     android:layout_height = "5dp"
     android:background = "@drawable/_line"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you,